# More efficient way for sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

RGN -> region names, NPR -> events that need to be counted for every region, RGF -> filters for regions. So in NPR i have event with car plates, i need to count them for every region, and split that to 7 days of the week. My solution is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.NAME,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as MON,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as TUE, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as WED, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as THU, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as FRI, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as SAT, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as SUN 
FROM RGN a 
LEFT JOIN NPR b 
ON a.ID IN  (
SELECT c.RGID
FROM RGF c
WHERE RTRIM(b.NUM) like RTRIM((REPLACE(c.RGFLT,'?','_')))
)
Group by a.NAME;
```

In filter i need to replace `?` with `_` to get `like()` expression.

This query gives me good results, but with 4 mil records in database its like 20 minutes to get it. Do you have any idea how to do exactly the same but more efficient ?

P.S. I tried with SUM() instead of count but it do not change anything.

@Edit my next try is `SELECT FROM NPR` and `join RGN`, its a bit faster but not enough.

Comment: You can remove DISTINCT here since your GROUP BY will return distinct rows..

Comment: Its working faster with distinct than w/o it.

Comment: It does??? Which dbms?

Comment: ms sql server 2008, with only 100k rows its 12,682 sec with `DISTINCT` and 12,761 sec w/o anyway with milion rows the difference is bigger

Comment: Different execution plans?

Comment: Did you try instead of selecting and groupng by Name , select and group by region ID?

Comment: do you have an execution plan? if yes, where does it spend most of the time?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri execution time: 12,886 sec, when grouping by ID

Comment: @Aツ The most time is spent on Table Spool

Comment: To improve performance, you need to fix the data structure so you can get rid of the `like` in the correlated subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.NAME,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as MON,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as TUE, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as WED, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as THU, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as FRI, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as SAT, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,b.TM) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as SUN
FROM RGN a, RGF c
left JOIN NPR b
ON RTRIM(b.NUM) like RTRIM((REPLACE(c.RGFLT,'?','_')))
WHERE a.ID = c.RGID AND b.TM BETWEEN
Group by a.RGNAME
```

Execution time with 100k rows ~4s, good enough since it was ~12s